# Force character variables to same length

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm exporting data to be analyzed in another application, and the different lengths of the ID variable is messing up the sorting of the data by ID because the external application is right-aligning the IDs. For example, some of the IDs are ATL, some other BC, and so on. You would expect ATL to sort before BC. But right-aligned ATL is `<space>ATL`, and BC is `<space><space>BC`, which sorts before `<space>ATL`.

I was able to work around this problem by appending some number of '_' to the end of each ID. But I had to subset the data set by the `str_length()` of the ID, and then `stc_c()` the appropriate number of '_' to each ID, and then `bind_rows()` all the subsets together. (What makes this unweildy method necessary is that `rep()` is not vectorized, I think. I could get a column of the data frame to indicate the number of underscore characters to append, but I couldn't figure out how to do it for each ID. If `unum` is the column with the number of underscores needed `paste0(rep("_", unum), collapse='')` gives me an error `invalid 'times' argument`.)

The IDs in this case are of length 2, 3, or 4, so it wasn't a big deal, but my work-around is inelegant and hard to generalize to the next case where there may be many different ID lengths.

Can anyone think of a tidy, efficient and general way to add an appropriate number of underscore characters to force all the IDs to the same left-aligned length?

TIA

Comment: Do you have some reproducible data?

Comment: Maybe `stringr::str_pad` is what you are looking for ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
library(stringr)
str_pad(df$ID, 8, side = "right", pad = "_")
```

Where the 8 here can be changed to give the desired string width.